# batch file calculator division remainder

Tags: batch-file, division, modulo

```
@echo off
title My Simple Calculator
echo What is the First Number you would like to Divide?
set /p number1=
echo What is the Second Number you would like to Divide?
set /p number2=
Set /A result = %number1% / %number2%
echo The answer is %result%.
pause
```

Hi. Good Day. Just wanted to ask some help about this matter.Since I'm  " NEW " to programming. Subject is all about CMD Scripts. In my simple calculator,how can I display the remainder/s. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked to see what `HELP SET` has to say? Or done some research on the net? You might find [SS64 on `SET`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) to be quite useful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no indication that the querent has made any effort to find the answer outside of SO.

Comment: sorry my bad then :(

Comment: Surely `Set /A result=number1/number2` followed by `Set /A remainder=number1-(result*number2)` would produce both, `%result%` and `%remainder%`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon my comment, and the information provided when entering `Set /?` at the Command Prompt, you can use grouping with the multiplication and subtraction arithmetic operators:

```bat
@Echo Off
Title My Simple Calculator
Set /P "number1=What is the number you would like to divide? "
Set /P "number2=What number would you like to divide %number1% by? "
Set /A result=number1/number2
Set /A remainder=number1-(result*number2)
Echo The answer is %result%, with a remainder of %remainder%.
Pause
```

Alternatively, you can also use the modulus arithmetic operator, `%`, *(which needs doubling if used in a batch file as opposed to the Command Prompt)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
Title My Simple Calculator
Set /P "number1=What is the number you would like to divide? "
Set /P "number2=What number would you like to divide %number1% by? "
Set /A result=number1/number2
Set /A remainder=number1%%number2
Echo The answer is %result%, with a remainder of %remainder%.
Pause
```

Comment: Woah thank you for your reply but when Ive tried it example 5 / 3  it gives me an answer 1.2 or 1 with a remainder of 2.The answer must be like 1.6 or 1.66666666667.Please help

Comment: @EdwardBandola The `Set /A` command is limited to 32bit signed integer math +/- ~2GB. If you need floatig point numbers switch to powershell.

Comment: @EdwardBandola, my answer provides exactly what your question asked, the result and the remainder! You should therefore accept the answer as the solution to your question and consider posting a new question, should you want to determine the result of an arithmetic calculation as a decimal.

Comment: @EdwardBandola: You have a misconception here. If the answer of 5 / 3 is 1.666666... then the _remainder_ is zero! The only way that the "division remainder" be not zero is with _integer arithmetic_ (where the result of 5 / 3 is 1).

Comment: Aha! I know now ! I should have ask for the result with decimals

Comment: @EdwardBandola, please follow the advice in my previous comment, thank you.

Comment: Thanks Compo but please enlighten me with these one since i dont get it right properly. It gives me a reminder thats not right

Comment: @EdwardBandola, click on the large check mark to the left of my answer to mark it as accepted, then create a new, properly formed floating point arithmetic question following the advice available from [ask], and remembering to include with it a properly formatted [mcve] of the code you require help with.